# IdownloadHandler is not working in WPF Cefsharp browser

Tags: wpf, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

```
 public class MyDownloadHandler : IDownloadHandler
    {
        public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnBeforeDownloadFired;
        public event EventHandler<DownloadItem> OnDownloadUpdatedFired;

        public void OnBeforeDownload(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IBeforeDownloadCallback callback)
        {
            SharedData.Log.Info(Constants.CONST_TEXT_LOG_DEBUG_DATA + Constants.CONST_TEXT_LOG_DEBUG_DATA_DELIMITER + "CEF OnBeforeDownload : started");
            OnBeforeDownloadFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);

            if (!callback.IsDisposed)
            {
                using (callback)
                {
                    callback.Continue(downloadItem.SuggestedFileName, showDialog: true);
                }
            }
            SharedData.Log.Info(Constants.CONST_TEXT_LOG_DEBUG_DATA + Constants.CONST_TEXT_LOG_DEBUG_DATA_DELIMITER + "CEF OnBeforeDownload : ended");
        }

        public void OnDownloadUpdated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, DownloadItem downloadItem, IDownloadItemCallback callback)
        {

            SharedData.Log.Info(Constants.CONST_TEXT_LOG_DEBUG_DATA + Constants.CONST_TEXT_LOG_DEBUG_DATA_DELIMITER + "CEF OnDownloadUpdated : started");
            OnDownloadUpdatedFired?.Invoke(this, downloadItem);
 }
```

Downloading progress bar is shown but download doesn't happen, `OnBeforeDownload` event is not working:

```
public DxLogin(string url)
{
  Cef.Initialize(cefSettings);
  dxloginpage = new ChromiumWebBrowser();
  dxloginpage.DownloadHandler = new MyDownloadHandler();
  InitializeComponent();
  dxloginpage.Address = url;
}
```

Comment: What version are you using? Is the OnBeforeDownload method being called? I don't see anywhere you've subscribed to your event.

Comment: Using latest version of cefsharp. I implemented same in windows application and its working fine, but WPF application events are not working. I tried calling onbeforedownload event, still didnt worked

Comment: Please specify the exact version you are using please. I'm not aware of any specific issues with the WPF version and I've had no other reports.

Comment: CefSharp v - 75.1.143.0 and WPF v-3.0.6920.4902

Comment: Can you fork https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample and provide an example of your code,  please squash all your changes in a single commit. Please only include changes relevant to reproducing the problem.

Comment: Its working fine.Thank you for your time